# Radio Button Value from Database C#

Tags: c#, sql, database, ms-access

I am trying to get my program to read a value from a particular cell in my Access database so that I can assign that value to the text property of a radio button. I am however getting an error I can't figure out the problem to. This is my code:

```
private void WindowsAnalysisQuiz_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //declare connection string using windows security
    string cnString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\Hannah\\Desktop\\WindowsAnalysisQuiz.accdb";

   //declare Connection, command and other related objects
   OleDbConnection conGet = new OleDbConnection(cnString);
   OleDbCommand cmdGet = new OleDbCommand();
   try
   {
       //open connection
       conGet.Open();

       cmdGet.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
       cmdGet.Connection = conGet;
       //cmdGet.CommansText = "SELECT 
       cmdGet.CommandText = "SELECT Question FROM WindowsAnalysisQuiz ORDER BY rnd()";

       OleDbDataReader reader = cmdGet.ExecuteReader();
       reader.Read();
       label1.Text = reader["Question"].ToString();
       radioButton.Text = cnString["Quiz"].Rows[0]["Correct Answer"].ToString();
       radioButton1.Text = reader["Answer2"].ToString();
       radioButton2.Text = reader["Answer3"].ToString();
       radioButton3.Text = reader["Answer4"].ToString();
       conGet.Close();
   }
}
```

I am having the problem with the line beginning with radioButton.Text. Apparently it has some invalid arguments and argument 1 cannot convert from string to int

Comment: The error is thrown because you are trying to access the string `cnString` via indexer which only accepts an integer index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are using several different RadioButtons, when you might really want a RadioButtonList.

If you have a RadioButtonList, it is easy to bind something to it, in essence create a list (from your database or whatever) and then bind this to the radio button list..something like

```
        var de = new List<string>();
        de.Add("1");
        de.Add("2");
        de.Add("3");

        RadioButtonList1.DataSource = de;
        RadioButtonList1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't your code be something like the following:

```
radioButton.Text = reader["Correct Answer"].ToString();
```

And change your select statement to:

```
cmdGet.CommandText = "SELECT Question, [Correct Answer], Answer2, Answer3, Answer4 FROM WindowsAnalysisQuiz ORDER BY rnd()";
```

Comment: What I am getting because of this is a messagebox saying 'Correct Answer'. I want the actual value in cell in the 1st column, 3rd row in this case to appear next to the actual radio button :)